# What is the equivalent Linux shell command in Windows Command?

Tags: linux, command-line, shell

I have a Linux command written as below:

```
$ ((cat file1.csv file2.csv | qs +) ; (cat file3.csv file4.csv | qs +)) | qs + |qs total | qs flip | qs mean
```

What is the equivalent code for Windows Command Shell?

I have checked this post [Is there a difference between `;` and `&&` and `|`? [duplicate]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159489/is-there-a-difference-between-and-and?newreg=471eb989448d462f875192a732fef430), but I could not understand the pipe usage in Linux above.

Thank you.

Comment: if you have a version of "qs" (whatever it does) that runs properly under the Windows Command Shell (that is, it reads standard input and writes to standard output) it should work if you to substitute "cat" with "type" and each ";" with a single "&"

Comment: Do you know what is the equivalent command for "|" (aka pipes) in Windows Command Shell?

Comment: The Windows Command Shell has the "|" command. if you do "DIR \WINDOWS | MORE" you will see a listing of the Windows directory, paged by the more command  -- just out of curiosity, what is the qs command you have in the question?

Comment: qs is just a command line tool file and + is the 1st input argument. + is an action which requires 2 csv file.